# What PostgreSQL admin GUI interface support SSH tunnelling?

Tags: postgresql

What PostgreSQL admin GUI interface support SSH tunnelling?

Most of the time the access to PostgreSQL is limited to few destination but if you are "mobile" developer or admin you will have a lot of trouble connecting to your DB servers.

I will assume that you can establish SSH connections to the machine and use tunnelling.

Now the question is what GUI tool can use to administer these DB instances - PgAdmin3 does not supports SSL tunnels.

Do not forget to specify, the platform, I am interested more about OS X but Windows and Linux are welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell PgAdmin3 to connect locally and tell that local connection to do a port forward using SSH. Works for OSX.

http://www.ur-ban.com/blog/2010/10/25/ssh-tunnels-with-postgres-pgadmin/

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/38-PuTTY-for-SSH-Tunneling-to-PostgreSQL-Server.html

Comment: I know it works but I want a solution that does not require me to manually establish these.

Comment: Well, just set it up once and make a script that starts your connection on booting your pc.

Comment: I an wondering if there is an utility on OS X that can be used to watch if you try to connect to a range of ports and if the connection fails, to try to build a tunnel, something like a transparent tunnel-on-demand.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea, not using SSH, but SSL instead (achieving a similar goal), you could enable SSL on your PostgreSQL server and connect to it via pgAdmin directly (verify-full preferable).

Answer (score 4):

SQLectron is opensource and it does support SSH tunneling. Works on windows, OSX and Linux.

http://sqlectron.github.io

Comment: Looks very promising. While pgAdmin4 hangs on remote SSH Tunneled connections, SQLelectron works and is much faster! Although it has only basic functionality. But the worst part is that it is not maintained anymore :( https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui/issues/433

Comment: yeah, the lack of contributions and the stop of user of maintainers (due not usage of relational database in the daily work) has made the sqlectron unmaintained as it is opensource and free, we still believe someone would assume the project and keep the development going on, in the other hand the current versions are quite stable so the usage of the software still possible.

Answer (score 0):

[EMS SQL Manager for PostgreSQL](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/manager) includes SSH tunneling in paid version. I've used it for years, works reliably and even supports key-based authentication. There is also free version, that is in many ways superior product compared to PgAdmin, but for some reason not very well known in PostgreSQL community.

**NB!** Shortcut-compatbile with Toad!

Answer (score 0):

The client pgAdmin III has this feature. Simply open the 3rd tab "SSH Tunnelling" when creating a new server

[image: ssh tunneling]

Comment: In the latest version of PgAdmin 4, there is no SSH tunnel anymore. And PuTTY need be set up for the SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found [DBeaver](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver) [from a user in the [comments](https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui/issues/433#issuecomment-376573284) of the now, un-maintained SQLectron].

If you've ever used Oracle's SQL Developer, you'll feel right at home with DBeaver.